# Turning a repository (ZIP downloaded) into suitable Git repository

Tags: git

When one downloads a Git repository in ZIP format and it is extracted to a folder, then in this folder, the command `git init` is executed. Now, is there a way to make the folder a suitable Git repository by changing configurations? I know it bundles into a command `git clone`. But still, I have a git repository without a proper git configuration suitable for further committing changes into the remote repository. This way, one saves the bandwidth needed in `git clone` because Git repository in ZIP format was downloaded from another computer and it is copied to my machine. So, I can make changes in codebase from my computer and add+commit+push only changed files.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What's wrong with `git clone`?

Answer (score 3):

A zipfile downloaded from e.g. github is missing the original repository's `.git` directory.

So it is merely a "snapshot" of the repository at a certain time; it doesn't contain the commit history.

If you want to contribute back to the original repository, you'll have to use `git clone`. Otherwise the original repository has no way of knowing which of its commit was used as the basis for your work.

*Update:* Do a `git clone` in a place that does not have download quotas and create a zipfile there, *including* the `.git` directory.

Comment: To the best of my knowlegde, you have to use `git clone`. But see updated answer.

Comment: @NeerajT `git clone` supports different protocols like HTTPS, ftp and rsync. Are all of them blocked?

Comment: @NeerajT Is it the site being blocked, or is it the protocol? You say HTTPS is allowed, so that suggests it's not the protocol, but the fact that you're able to download ZIP files suggests that it's not the site either.